# How should I shorten this line of Python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pep8

Here is the line that needs to be shortened.

```
tree_top = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(sys.argv[1])))
```

- Should I create a variable for each procedure?
- Should I alias `os.path,abspath`, `os.path.expandvars` and `os.path.expanduser` to have shorter names?
- Should I use backslashes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a feature of Python called [Implicit Line Joining](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/implicit-joining.html).

Code that is between parentheses is implicitly part of the same instruction, therefore, you can 'shorten' your expression by spreading it in multiple lines:

```
tree_top = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.expanduser(
        os.path.expandvars(
            sys.argv[1]
        )
    )
)
```

Now, each line comes under 80 characters and is clean PEP8 code.

If each step of your operation was more clearly defined, using intermediary variables would also be a good way to shorten each individual lines. In some cases, it can help make the code clearer, but here the intermediary steps are less useful

Comment: Implicit Line Joining  is beautiful. I will be using this a lot

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to reduce the width is to use implicit line continuation within parentheses:

```
tree_top = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.expanduser(
        os.path.expandvars(sys.argv[1])
    )
)
```

Alternatively, just select the parts of `os.path` that you need:

```
from os.path import abspath, expanduser, expandvars

tree_top = abspath(expanduser(expandvars(sys.argv[1])))
```

or use some combination of the two.